# How can I convince my boss that investing in Adobe CC is more beneficial than using GIMP?

Tags: business

I have recently been employed to a hotel management company as creative designer. Apparently, the guy who used to work at the company was using GIMP, Fireworks and Sony Vegas to do most designs and post production. At this point my employer refuses to spend any type of money to get Adobe CC, even though I have let her know that it will be more productive for me to work with Adobe software.

She asked me one question at the interview: "Are you familiar with GIMP?" .. and dumb enough, I said YES. Now she's slamming it back to me as "Well you told me that you can use GIMP, so get on with it, plus the previous designer was working pretty well with it".

Obviously I can use GIMP, but the workflow on Adobe products is way better and I can work twice as fast. How can I convince her to get to pay for the Abobe CC package?

Comment: It sounds like you were hired on the premise that you could use GIMP... In which case, money-saving was probably a motivating factor for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to convince people is that you are more productive on one software and the cost benefit worths it.

Dowload for one month the trial of photoshop, and show him with more productivity, quality or inventive (because you have more freedom).

Make her a bet. If she feels the diference, she will buy a licence.

In case you can not use the trial version, because someone already did it,  buy the photography plan which is only 9.99 a month. You can use your own personal licence on the offcie, with the premise it is on your computer and it is your licence.

Comment: You and @Ryan have valid point. Thank you guys

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't convince her at all right now. She told you it would be with Gimp, you accepted the position, for now don't make waves.

Prove your worth and value, then as the assignments and workload increase you can start to make suggestions.

Instead of asking yourself, "How can I convince my boss to spend money" you should be asking yourself, "What limits am I facing?" Then when those limits are met you can ask for additional software.

This is almost always the case I might add in the business world.

Comment: This is very true of most types of work, regardless of what you're doing. When starting at a new company with the perspective of an outsider, it's very likely you'll see things that could be much more efficient, but as a new employee, you haven't earned the credentials to ask for changes. The time to broach this topic is after you've proved your worth.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously money is the thing you should be targetting. But first let me explain a critical point. It is not really easy to convince a boss for spending money if the boss feels its a luxury item. It is perfectly possible that claim coming from you will sound like a excuse for a better toy. Problem is that any claim for efficiency is easily manipulated by you.

So it would be better for you to get somebody else to point this out for you. For me the tool in question was SnagIt and i couldnt get snagit untill our secretary pointed out that I had been using extra 10 hours this week gluing together screen captures and that this would be projected to cost the company a few thousand dollars just because the boss wanted to save 50.

In your case this secondary person might be the printing service, or a external collaborator complaining about something. Be careful though not to look incompetent.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need Photoshop and not the entire suite, you might just spend 10$ from your own money and pay for the licence, if this will work twice as fast for you then 10$ a month is worth it !

Comment: Why should he work at twice the pace at 10$ less salary? Didnt downvote. I would pay 10$ for my own sanity though. Didnt downvote.

Comment: Voting up because this is what I would do. But OP does say the previous person used Vegas as well so I'm thinking OP might want Premier and/or After Effects which means $50/mo for a personal license.